# Cómo obtener un número aleatorio con decimales y enteros en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Puedo obtener números aleatorios en un rango personalizado, con:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * ( maximo - minimo + 1 ) + minimo )
```

### Ejemplo:

```js
var max = 10,
    min = 4,
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    
    console.log(random);
```

---

Pero, cómo puedo obtener números entre cierto rango, incluyendo decimales entre ellos ?

Por ejemplo, quiero obtener los números del 1 - 3 , y el primer decimal incluido, las opciones serían:

```
[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 .... 3] ,
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo en JavaScript ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pensalo de la siguiente forma: un aleatorio entre 4 y 10 con 1 decimal sería lo mismo que uno entre 40 y 100, dividido por 10, ¿no? ... Bien, generalizando:

```
//Aleatorio entre min y max (incluyendo a max) con n decimales
//
function aleatorio(minimo, maximo, decimales) {
    var precision = Math.pow(10, decimales);
    minimo = minimo*precision;
    maximo = maximo*precision;
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maximo-minimo+1) + minimo) / precision;
}
```

---

Demo:

```js
function aleatorio(minimo, maximo, decimales) {
    var precision = Math.pow(10, decimales);
    minimo = minimo*precision;
    maximo = maximo*precision;
    
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(maximo-minimo+1) + minimo) / precision;
}


//Calcular
document.getElementById("calc")
    .addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (event) {
            var min = document.getElementById("min").value,
                max = document.getElementById("max").value,
                decimales = document.getElementById("decimales").value,
                resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
            
            resultado.innerText = aleatorio(min,max,decimales);
        }
    );
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Min:
<input id="min" type="number" value="1">
Max:
<input id="max" type="number" value="3">
Decimales:
<input id="decimales" type="number" value="1">
<input id="calc" type="button" value="Calcular">
Aleatorio:
<pre id="resultado" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Lo principal sería remover el `floor` así se evita truncar el decimal y evitar retornar solo un entero remover el  `+1` para evitar tomar valores mayores al número pasado como máximo,

```js
var max = 3,
min = 1 ,
//Retorna un número aleatorio entre min (incluido) y max (excluido)
random = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
console.log(random);
```

Si desea limitar la cantidad  de decimales siempre puede recurrir a `toFixed` , *(2 para el ejemplo)*

```js
var max = 3,
min = 1 ,
random = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed(2);
console.log(random);
```

Comment: `toFixed()` redondea al número, haciendo que no tenga una distribución lineal en los extremos. Eso hace que no sea completamente aleatorio... El `1.0` se forma redondeando el rango `[1.0..1.005)`; y el `1.01` con el rango `[1.005..1.015)`... Los rangos no son iguales, por lo que no van a tener la misma probabilidad.